# ssis derived column - check if date field is null

Tags: sql-server, ssis, null, etl, derived-column

In SSIS derived column I need to check if a Date field is empty or null, I'm using this expression but I got an error:

```
TRIM([date field]) == "" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : TRIM([date field])
```

The field is of `DT_DATE` data type. What's wrong in that?

I've used expressions like this successfully:

```
TRIM(String_field) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,255) : TRIM(String_field)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are combining data types (if true is a date and false is a string).

This is the correct formula:

```
TRIM([date field]) == "" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)TRIM([date field])
```

I am assuming [date field] is a string.

Comment: and what if [date field] is dt_date?

Comment: @marko be aware that this expression does not handles nulls.

Comment: @marko --> if [date field] was a date then both of your tests fail. the TRIM() as well as  = ""

Comment: This solution will throw an exception if the field contains NULL

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the error, it is related to the derived column result data type, since in conditional operators (`?:`) both true and false expression must generate the same data type.

In addition, your expression doesn't check for NULL values, you should use the following expression:

```
TRIM(REPLACENULL([date field],"")) == "" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)TRIM([date field])
```

Also, you have to make sure that [date field] can be parsed as date, so `(DT_DATE)TRIM([date field])` will not throw an exception, you can use the error output to handles the value that doesn't contain a valid date.